# Polymorphic return types in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference, polymorphism

I've seen some posts regarding the issue but not something that sums all the options I have at my current situation, and there might be solutions I haven't considered.

My situation is quite general I have a couple of classes `Inf1` `Inf2` (which are more like interfaces) both have pure virtual methods.

Where `Inf1` has a method

`(Inf2& or Inf2* or shared_pointer) foo(/** Some info on how to build the object**/) = 0`

(this is part of the problem).

In the implementations of `Inf1` return various implementations of `Inf2` when implementing `foo`.

The `Inf2` implementations are relatively small so I wouldn't mind returning them by value so they are copy constructed to the result, but I cannot declare `foo` to return just `Inf2` because then I'd be returning an abstract object.

Any preferable and or creative ways to solve this? :)

Comment: What's you question? If you should use Inf2&, Inf2* or a shared pointer?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Inf2>` if the caller has to take ownership of the object. Really, there aren't (m)any other options.

Comment: @bennofs Exactly, what would be the least cumbersome, clearest nicest, neatest solution that will not get me nasty stares at the office (and no we don't use boost :\ so standard solutions only)

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve, and what the actual `inf2` is [who owns it?]. If the instance of `Inf2` is held in some central storage location, then it should be a reference. Otherewise a shared pointer is probably the best choice.

Comment: It may not be a polymorpic return type, but why not use function templates http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ to solve your problem unless it is an academic one?

Comment: @Inge Because function templates only work if this is a compile-time decision. Often it isn’t (any kind of factory method).

Comment: @IngeHenriksen as Konrad wisely deducted it is some sort of a factory method so this is not a compile time decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have types `Inf1` and `Inf2`, which are related to each other, and at least one of them contains abstract methods.

You want to return some sub-implementation of `Inf2`, but which one is decided at run time.

This means you need run time polymorphism.  There are 3 different ways you could approach this.

First, you could return a pointer -- probably a smart pointer, like `unique_ptr`, to the common interface.  This requires free store (heap) allocation, but makes ownership clear, and is the simplest answer.

Second, you could write a type erasure object which exposes a non-`virtual` version of the `Inf2` interface, and forwards to some internal details.  These internal details will end up using a smart pointer of some kind, or the third solution.  The advantage here is that you can hide how you manage memory, and simply expose value semantics with cheap move.  The disadvantage is that there is lots of boilerplate.

Third, you could use something like a `boost::variant` -- a `union` over a set of types with means to guard against accessing the wrong types.  While `boost` may not directly be used, the design can be mimiced.  The idea is that you have some local storage in which you placement new the data, except maybe for larger objects, where you have a smart pointer you use instead.  Unlike the second solution, the set of types you support are explicitly listed in your type.  This is the hardest solution (if you don't have access to `boost` at least), and requires that you have a fixed (at compile time) set of implementations of `Inf2` that all users of `Inf1` have to have full details on.

As noted, the first solution is the easiest.  The costs to the first solution are merely performance based, and those performance hits wouldn't be hard to fix after the fact if you discovered they where real issues.  So I would advise solution #1, and then profile to see if the costs involved are too high.  If the costs are high, move to solution #3, possibly in a solution #2 wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really about memory management.  Polymorphic subclasses of `Inf2` can be arbitrarily large, and the largest isn't known at compile-time, so you can't store them with automatic storage duration, therefore they cannot be returned by value - so you need to manage memory for them somehow at least across the return

Where shall objects of an `Inf2` subclass type be stored?  And when and from where shall implementations of `Inf2` be deleted.  The answer to this will generally dictate what kind of handle concept to use.  For example if you allocate Inf2 implementations in a memory pool then returning `Inf2*` is fine.  You can also use `unique_ptr<Inf2>` if you want to do single ownership, but then you can't copy the handle.  You can also use `shared_ptr<Inf2>` if you want to copy the handles, but you have to be careful about cycles, and it is slightly less efficient.  You can also create a wrapper class `Inf2Handle` that does something more sophisticated, such as copy-on-write, or other things.

You mentioned that implementations are small so perhaps a memory pool is the best architecture.

Which is the best choice really depends on the bigger picture of how `Inf1` and `Inf2` are to be used.